# sendmail with RoR: not receiving mails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, sendmail

I am using sendmail in my Rails app. The configrations are as given below,

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost' }
  config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'no-reply@example.com'}
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
```

When I restart my apache2 server and sendmail service, I will get a mail(one time). However, if, later, I try to send the mail, it shows the status as 200-ok, but I won't receive any mail.

FYI:

Same issue is found even for `localhost:3000`

Also below is my mail.log output

```
Nov 25 17:58:02 dosysnet267 sendmail[1602]: sAPCS2X3001602: Authentication-Warning: dosysnet267.dreamorbit.in: DREAMORBIT\\karthik.ds set sender to no-reply@gmail.com using -f
Nov 25 17:58:02 dosysnet267 sendmail[1602]: sAPCS2X3001602: from=no-reply@gmail.com, size=473, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<547475d2aa8c3_5dc181896c66978@dosysnet267.mail>, relay=DREAMORBIT\\karthik.ds@localhost
Nov 25 17:58:03 dosysnet267 sm-mta[1604]: sAPCS2bg001604: from=<no-reply@gmail.com>, size=774, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<547475d2aa8c3_5dc181896c66978@dosysnet267.mail>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Nov 25 17:58:03 dosysnet267 sendmail[1602]: sAPCS2X3001602: to=karthik.ds@example.com, ctladdr=no-reply@gmail.com (1200096887/1200095745), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=30473, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (sAPCS2bg001604 Message accepted for delivery)
Nov 25 17:58:05 dosysnet267 sm-mta[1609]: sAPCS2bg001604: to=<karthik.ds@example.com>, delay=00:00:03, xdelay=00:00:02, mailer=esmtp, pri=120774, relay=example.com. [174.136.95.75], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK)
```

Any idea?

Comment: can you share the code that is called to sent that email?

Comment: UserMailer.welcome_user(self).deliver!

Comment: oh! seems okey to me. Btw, did you check your spam folder?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yup, I have checked but there are no mails.

Comment: okey, seems nothing I can help here. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

When i need to send a email when testing an rails app do i all ways use this code inside the development file. Then just fill it out with your gmail credentials. The rails app will then send the email through gmail with your gmail account.

```
config/environments/development.rb

config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port                 => 587,
:domain               => 'gmail.com',
:user_name            => 'youremail@gmail.com',
:password             => 'yourpassword',
:authentication       => 'plain',
:enable_starttls_auto => true  }
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for looking into the issue. It is working fine. I couldn't receive mails, due to my mailbox issues.